# Какой знак препинания после слова "означает"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, двоеточие

*Слово "Дхарма" означает то, для чего ты родился*

или

*Слово "Дхарма" означает означает: ‘то, для чего ты родился’?*

Answer (score 1):

Слово *Дхарма* означает "то,  для чего ты родился".

Пояснение

Дхарма -  слово, употреблявшееся в древней и средневековой литературе Индии для выражения самых разнообразных понятий: закон, религия, долг, справедливость, душа, обычай и т.д. Из всего этого   основным является понятие, охватывающее **круг налагаемых на человека  религиозных, нравственных, общественных, семейных обязанностей**...

Comment: Скажите, а слово "Дхарма" не нужно брать в кавычки? И правильно ли будет использовать для "то, для чего ты..." марровские кавычки?